# Truncation of long strings in DataSet items

Tags: front-end, dataset, visualization

Given a dataset containing items with long texts (strings), Mathematica would automatically truncate those texts after 3 lines

```
Dataset[<| 
  "Abstract" -> 
   "\n  Measurement of the inclusive and differential top-quark \
charge asymmetry is\ncarried out using full Run \
2 data from proton-proton collisions at a\ncenter-of-mass energy of \
$13$ TeV collected by the ATLAS detector. The\nsingle-lepton and \
dilepton $t\\bar{t}$ decay channels are combined. Distorting\n\
detector effects are removed using fully Bayesian unfolding. In the \
dilepton\ndecay channel, the leptonic \
charge asymmetry is determined. Results from the\nmeasurements are \
compared with the Standard Model prediction. The excess of\ncharge \
asymmetry from zero charge-asymmetry hypothesis at the level of $4.7$\
\nstandard deviations is observed.\n", 
  "Link" -> "https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.00161"|> , 
 ItemSize -> {Automatic, 10}]
```

[image]

Is there any way to make it show more lines? Notice that using something like
`DateSet[...,ItemSize -> {Automatic, 10}]` would only increase the amount of white space around the text but would not produce more lines.

Comment: `ItemDisplayFunction -> (# &)` ?

Comment: @Syed Many thanks! This is precisely the solution. If you care about writing an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: I am glad I was able to help you. Please take care.

Comment: @vsht if Syed doesn't want to write an answer, you could write it yourself, and get all the reputation points! Answering your own question is encouraged. Just try to make it a good answer, with tidy code, explanation and an example of the output. (just like your good question!)